# Iphone IOS, Accessing audio data from another audio session

Tags: ios, audio, itunes, ipod, audiosession

I'm in the process of building an app that uses the IPod Library Access API, so that I can play songs from iTunes in the app. However I also need to access the audio data of whatever song is playing, like how a music visualizer would.

So far, looking through the Audio Session documentation and the Core Audio documentation, I haven't found any officially supported means of achieving this. As I understand it, it would require accessing audio data from another audio session, as in the iPod access api, technically iTunes is playing in the background as I understand it and thus has a different audio session.

So basically how can you access audio data from another audio session? Specifically getting the audio data of songs played through the iPod Access API?

Answer (score 0):

See the AudioTapProcessor iOS Sample sample app in Apple's iOS Developer Library (sign on required), for the use of the AVFoundation MTAudioProcessingTap API.